# Calling a Postgres stored function SQL error

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, jdb

Im calling a stored function like the following:

```
PreparedStatement deleteAll=connection.prepareStatement("{ call delete_all_data() }");
deleteAll.execute();
```

And in the logs i see:

```
15:16:31,950  WARN SqlExceptionHelper:143 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
15:16:31,950 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:144 - ERROR: syntax error at or near "{"
  Position: 1
```

what is wrong with the prepareStatement??

Comment: You should use `CallableStatement` for stored procedures.

Comment: `connection.prepareStatement("select delete_all_data()")` is enough. No `CallableStatement` needed

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza A JDBC driver should also support the call escape with `Statement` and `PreparedStatement`. This should work as long as the stored procedure doesn't have `OUT` parameters (`PreparedStatement`) or parameter placeholders (for `Statement`). However in practice most drivers only support it with `CallableStatement`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `connection.prepareStatement` (which expects SQL) to `connection.prepareCall`. That may very well be the only change you need, as a `CallableStatement` is a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: See my comment on the question itself, although this is probably the solution, it is not according to specification: the call escape should also be supported on `Statement` and `PreparedStatement`. See: section 6.4 of JDBC 4.2 and http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2013-January/000030.html

Answer (score 2):

I use prepareCall to call stored procedures.

```
String SQL = "{call delete_all_data()}";
cstmt = conn.prepareCall (SQL);
```